# Kentico 9 - Page Type attachment - get allowed extensions via API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

We have a stand alone MVC application and need to get the list of allowed attachment file extensions that are shown in the admin application page type management interface.

We need this to validate that files uploaded via the Kentico API in our MVC application are within the allowed extensions for the page type.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/API9/Settings) for getting settings using Kentico API.  If you look in Modules>CMS>Settings, you can get the actual name of the setting key you will need.  I believe the specific one you're looking for is `CMSUploadExtensions`

Comment: It looks like this is for sitewide settings.  I am looking for how to access the individual field allowed extensions for a specific page type.